# Generating sequnce of alphabets dynamically

Tags: java, character

I have a requirement where I need to create sequence like A:A, A:B......so on till A:Z
Here I will be storing firstName as A and LastName as A then will call API which gives me results based on this criteria. In the next iteration first name will A and last name will be B and so on till first name is "A" and last name is "Z"

This can be achieved by two for loops and I will get results from A:A to Z:Z.

The catch here is suppose, the end system fails to process query with first name: A and lastName: F then I want the search to begin with firstName: A and lastName:**FA**. This should continue till FZ i.e A:FA ....A:FZ. After this is done, the iteration should begin with firstName: A and lastName G and so on.

In short, at any combination if there is an error, I have to dynamically append A - Z to the lastName and call my API and continue.

Highly appreaciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just add another for-loop , when an error occures, like this:

```
String[26] alphabet = {"A", "B",...};
for(int i = 0;i<26;i++){
//request
if(Error occures){
Stringbuilder sb = new Stringbuilder(2);
for(int j = 0; j<26; j++){
   sb.append(alphabet[i]); //append the first character
   sb.append(alphabet[j]); // append the second character
   //request sb.toString()
   sb.deleteCharAt(1); // "reset"
   sb.deleteCharAt(0); // "reset"

}
```

But this solution doesn´t work, when an error occures again.
If you want to repeat the loop when an error occures in the second loop,
use a function like this:

```
String[26] alphabet = {"A", "B",...};
for(int i = 0;i<26;i++){

if(error){
Stringbuilder Strb = new Stringbuilder();
Strb.append(alphabet[i]);
requestwithmoreExt(
}
public void requestwithmoreExt(Stringbuilder sb){
for(int j = 0; j<26; j++){
sb.append(alphabet[j]); // append the second character
//request sb.toString();
if(error){
requestwithmoreExt(sb);
}
for(int k = 0;k<sb.length();k++){
sb.deleteCharAt(k);
}

}
}
```

but note, this is recursive! if errors occure too often, the string will
grow to infinity!!!

Comment: And also it should be dynamic. For example if there is an error for the combination A: AA, then iteration should begin with A:AAA till A:AAZ, then come back to A:AB and complete A:AZ and then start with A:B to A:Z and finally Z:Z.